# How to turn datetime hours in columns, datetime days in rows and fill up the dataframe with the value of a single column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I have to extract the column "Demand" for the year 2021 of a dataframe called "df_csv".

I created a new dataframe, called df2, only have the columns datetime (YYYY-MM-DD %H:%M:%S) and Demand.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df2 = df_csv[(df_csv['date'] >= '2021-01-01') & (df_csv['date'] <= '2021-12-31')]

df2 = df2[['date','Demand']]

df2

# My current output:

date                    Demand
2021-01-01 00:00:00 22001.4
2021-01-01 01:00:00 20397.7
2021-01-01 02:00:00 19203.1
2021-01-01 03:00:00 18578.0
2021-01-01 04:00:00 18409.2
...                     ...
```

Once I get this new dataframe I need to put hours as columns, days as rows and fill up this new dataframe with the values of Demand. Getting an array of 365x24.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": pd.date_range("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31 23:00:00", freq="H"),
    "Demand": np.random.rand(365 * 24)
})

out = df.pivot_table(index=df["date"].dt.date, columns=df["date"].dt.hour, values="Demand")
```

```
date              0         1         2         3         4   ...        19        20        21        22        23
date                                                          ...
2021-01-01  0.394998  0.222697  0.526181  0.627760  0.432546  ...  0.497067  0.855186  0.692403  0.721329  0.471294
2021-01-02  0.766524  0.792078  0.861956  0.704437  0.994023  ...  0.534063  0.573440  0.504310  0.931782  0.791618
2021-01-03  0.426928  0.207534  0.450191  0.436574  0.538557  ...  0.312004  0.076502  0.982862  0.601844  0.334993
2021-01-04  0.007181  0.846478  0.280916  0.480186  0.018973  ...  0.136658  0.066533  0.715734  0.617086  0.513928
2021-01-05  0.824114  0.096845  0.784100  0.813216  0.862855  ...  0.393092  0.546962  0.221178  0.311744  0.153691
...              ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
2021-12-27  0.486944  0.067749  0.262450  0.240502  0.981808  ...  0.623611  0.304373  0.308532  0.891595  0.983024
2021-12-28  0.757574  0.528425  0.763380  0.357143  0.975557  ...  0.430134  0.123310  0.041141  0.720926  0.963683
2021-12-29  0.846010  0.626735  0.800993  0.364559  0.550821  ...  0.849041  0.832457  0.532247  0.242686  0.303782
2021-12-30  0.739043  0.971650  0.041799  0.770373  0.929829  ...  0.885578  0.808826  0.198114  0.731289  0.689102
2021-12-31  0.746018  0.846874  0.790035  0.436726  0.636697  ...  0.423958  0.040684  0.719531  0.243232  0.198251

[365 rows x 24 columns]
```